# Converting Microsoft Security Essentials DateTime in registery to readable format

Tags: powershell, scripting, windows-registry, ms-security-essentials

I am trying to get some data from the Windows Registery using Windows Powershell (5.0+), specifically data of Microsoft Security Essentials.

I managed to decode almost all of it and convert it to a human readable output. However, Microsoft stores timestamps as a reg_binary type.

Sample key:

[image: example of reg_binary key]

Can anyone please help me to figure out how to get an understandable value out of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$data = Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\Scan" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty LastScanRun
$time = [DateTime]::FromFileTime( (((((($data[7]*256 + $data[6])*256 + $data[5])*256 + $data[4])*256 + $data[3])*256 + $data[2])*256 + $data[1])*256 + $data[0])
Get-Date $time -Format "mm/dd/yyyy"
```

source: ["To convert Reg_binary to Date"](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b430ac7d-668b-4be8-87bf-2bd9e6faf3d4/to-convert-regbinary-to-date?forum=winserverpowershell)